# Prove that $xy\le\frac{x^p}{p}+\frac{y^q}{q}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

Given $x\ge0$, $y\ge0$, $p>0$, $q>0$ such that $\dfrac{1}{p}+\dfrac{1}{q}=1$:

Prove that $xy\le\dfrac{x^p}{p}+\dfrac{y^q}{q}$ starting by $xy=1$

Comment: This is known as [Young's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young's_inequality).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function $\ln$ is concave on $(0,\infty)$ so for $x,y>0$

$$\ln\left(\frac1p x^p+\frac1q y^q\right)\ge\frac1p\ln x^p+\frac1q\ln y^q=\ln x+\ln y=\ln( xy)$$
hence applying the exponential function we find the desired inequality.